# Turn a cell blank if all three adjacent cells become blank

Tags: vba, excel

I am very inexperienced with VBA and coding in general.

I am working on a spreadsheet where column `A` is job numbers.
Column `B` is Dates.
Columns `C`, `D` and `E` you have to put a mark in E.G Text that has no pattern.

Now I have worked out code to put the date in column `B` if any mark is put in `C`, `D` or `E`. However if you then delete `C`, `D` or `E` the cell in column `B` is still populated with the date.

Just to be clear `C`, `D` or `E` could have text in them or on 2 or 1.

Now I know you could just delete the cell but where is the fun in that .

Here is the code I have so far please feel free to suggest way to make it smaller or clear it up, but mainly away to sort out my issue thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)    
    Call Macro1(Target)
    Call Macro2(Target)
    Call Macro3(Target)
End Sub

Sub Macro1(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("c2:c100")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, 0)
            .Value = Date
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub Macro2(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("d2:d100")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, -1)
            .Value = Date
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub

Sub Macro3(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("e2:e100")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, -2)
            .Value = Date
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code either inserts a date in Column B when columns C, D or E in that row are changed and at least one of them is non-blank. Conversely, the cell in Column B is cleared if all three are blank:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("c2:E100")) Is Nothing Then
    With Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Me.Range("B2:B100"))
        If WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Intersect(Target.EntireRow, Me.Range("C2:E100"))) <> 3 Then
            .Value = Date
            .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        Else
            .Value = ""
        End If
    End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm a little confused because it looks like your existing code will clear or add a date to column C, while your question refers to clearing or deleting from Column B.

Comment: 1) OPs code actually _acts_ on column "B" since 'Range("C1")(1,0).Address' returns "$B$1" and so do 'Range("D1")(1,-1).Address'  and 'Range("E1")(1,-2).Address' . 2) Furthermore I thought that date clearance should be allowed only if all cells in columns C to E are cleared (even if one by one). 3) Finally I always switch `Application.EnableEvents` to `False` and then back to `True` to avoid unwanted (and possibly dangerous) looping 4) I too thought about explicitly referencing the sheet but being in a `Worksheet_Change()` event handler make it sure the "Active" sheet is `Target` one

Comment: @user3598756, you are right of course on the addressing. On 2, who knows, I think you could be right, but it's not clear. On 3, while that's a good practice, it's unnecessary here since the code reacts to changes in C to E by changing B.

Comment: @user3598756, actually, on #2, the title does confirm your interpretation.

Comment: on #3 it's true: this code alone would just have one (useless)loop. But _who knows_ (and I'm with you on this point...) what else can there be?

Comment: @user3598756. It's just a balance between having a shorter example to deals just with what's asked and a longer one that tries to anticipate other issues. I think either way can be valid.

Comment: thank you Doug Glancy  it works well does all I asked, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

you just add a check

```
 If Target.Value = "" Then dateCell.ClearContents
```

where dateCell is the cell where the date resides in the current row

but you must also:

1. disable/enable events

   to prevent `Worksheet_Change()` fire again when changing "date" cell (this occurs also when deleting a cell value
2. use one sub to handle all three columns

   just check if target intersects columns C to E. like

   ```
   If Not Intersect(.Cells, Range("C:E")) Is Nothing Then
   ```

see code:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Call Macro1(Target)
End Sub

Sub Macro1(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim dateCell As Range
    With Target
        If .Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

        Application.EnableEvents = False '<--| disable events to prevent this one fire when changing "date" cell
        If Not Intersect(.Cells, Range("C:E")) Is Nothing Then
            Set dateCell = Cells(.row, "B") '<--| set the cell where "date" resides
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Parent.Cells(.row, "C").Resize(, 3)) = 0 Then '<--| if there are no values in current row columns C to E ...
                dateCell.ClearContents '<--|... clear the date
            Else
                dateCell.Value = Date '<--|... otherwise put the date in column B and ...
                dateCell.EntireColumn.AutoFit '<--| ... autofit column B
            End If
        End If
        Application.EnableEvents = True '<--| enable events back on
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You Very much user3598756,  it work well, does all that I asked, thanks again.